# bower package with a git specific file

Tags: node.js, bower

I am totally new to Bower/NodeJs land. Is it possible to include a specific file from a git repository.

For example I need https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js file from [angular.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js) repo.

Is it possible to include just a file from a repo as this?

```
 "dependencies": 
      "angular-my-file":"https://raw.github.com/angular/angular.js/master/src/Angular.js",
      "moment": "~2.1.0"
 },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is supporting. This is legal:

```
https://raw.github.com/angular/angular.js/master/src/Angular.js
```

See this thread:

https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/856